# How to enable cursor selector in GWT TextArea?

Tags: java, gwt, cursor, textarea, selection

In my application I call an API to get the contents of the file as a String and use the TextArea UIWidget to display the file content to the user.

I want the user to be able to select the text in the text area in order to be able to copy and paste the contents of the file. When I hover over the TextArea in GWT, text selection is not being enabled. The getCursorPos function in the TextArea seems to be useful when modifying the textarea but not for selections[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text selection is enabled in TextArea by default. You either disabled it somewhere `setEnabled(false)`, or you put another widget (panel) on top of your TextArea which prevents users from typing in or selecting a text.