# How to enable cursor selector in GWT TextArea while disabling text modification?

Tags: java, gwt, cursor, textarea, selection

In my application I call an API to get the contents of the file as a String and use the TextArea UIWidget to display the file content to the user.

When I enable cursor selector by setting the setEnaled(true) for the textarea, I see that it gives the user to modify the text. It also shows spell checks and other highlights.
I want to show the user the string giving him power to select text like in pdf while disabling the option to modify the text. 
Any pointers regarding how to do that?

Comment: Why would you use TextArea for this purpose? Why not simply show the text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable cursor selector in GWT TextArea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523119/how-to-enable-cursor-selector-in-gwt-textarea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `textArea.setReadonly(true)` instead of `.setEnabled(false)`.